# customise eclipse scout application look and feel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-scout

I am new to eclipse scout. My question is how do i customise the default application look and feel for an eclipse scout application. I want to be able to change the button colors and replace the default icons with my own. I was able to change some of the colors using the application.css file but i did not archieve much. Also, is there a way of getting the ids, or class names for the various components in the resulting web pages so that i can be more granular in styling them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How you can style an Eclipse Scout application depends on which front-end you use: RAP, Swing or SWT.

**Swing**

- You can use the [Scout Swing Spy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Spy) to determine the class name of a component in your UI when you have it selected.
- If you use the [Rayo look and feel](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/5.0/Rayo_Look_and_Feel), you can use implement the interface `ILookAndFeelConfigurator` and register it for the extension point `org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.swing.lafconfigurator` to change the theming by providing a custom XML. The [Rayo concept wiki article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Rayo#Use_a_custom_XML) explains this in more details.
- If you do not use  the Rayo LaF...

**RAP**

- The default RAP theme is modelled after the Rayo theme mentioned above.
- Changing it involves creating your own theme bundle and create the appropriate CSS file there. Given that it is a RAP theme, you'll have to refer to the [RAP RWT Theming guide](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=theming.html&version=3.0). See the Scout forum thread ["Scout Web App + CSS"](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=367983&goto=897730&#msg_897730).
- For reference, this is the Rayo CSS file of the Eclipse Scout 5.0 in [the eclipse scout git repository](http://git.eclipse.org/c/scout/org.eclipse.scout.rt.git/tree/org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.theme.rayo/theme?h=releases/5.0.x) (org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.theme.rayo)

**SWT**

- Given that the SWT UI is designed to be portable and uses the widgets provided by the operating system, the amount of customization is more limited.
- You can use the extension point `org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.swt.lookAndFeel` to adjust some values of the look and feel (see [schema file](http://git.eclipse.org/c/scout/org.eclipse.scout.rt.git/tree/org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.swt/schema/lookAndFeel.exsd)). See also the Scout thread ["Modifying SWT look and feel for disabled elements"](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/501277/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own button and you own icon by use photoshop first bro
then copy the file into res/drawable of your application project

Comment: i am using eclipse Luna. pardon me but where do i find this folder. the application is composed of 6 projects.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, res/drawable sounds like Android development to me. OP is referring to Eclipse Scout.